# how to prevent angular from replacing <link> elements

Tags: css, angular, webpack

I have an angular 13 project, in index.html I have

```
 <link
      href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
```

when building the app it replaces this element with its content

```
<style type="text/css">
      @font-face {
        font-family: "Roboto";
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-display: swap;
        src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2)
          format("woff2");
        unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF,
          U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
      }
...
</style>
```

I want to prevent Angular from this behavior and keep the element `<link>` as it.

I searched for something like `extractCss: false` but it deprecated

I thought about using custom-webpack to override plugins but I don't know how to do that (I know how to use custom-webpack, but don't know how to disable a plugin and which plugin should be disabled)

Comment: That should not be a default behavior of Angular. You can create a distributable version of a new angular project and see the index.html. It is as is. Maybe it's something in your pipeline that's causing this behavior?

Comment: I tested it on a fresh app without any modification, the same issue occurs

Comment: In angular.json try to disable font optimization: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#fonts-optimization-options